# What happened to Myrcella Baratheon?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I have only seen the series and not read any of the books.

Tyrion marries off Cersei's daughter, Myrcella Baratheon into the Dorne family.

Later Oberyn Martell arrives planning revenge against the Lannisters.

Oberyn and Cersei talk in front of a boat. She says it is a gift for her daughter but you get the feeling it is a bribe to him for her daughter's safety.

Oberyn states that they do not make slaves of princesses in Dorne and Cersei counters that they do not rape princesses in King's Landing; a statement we are lead to believe is false.

This scene implies that Myrcella is not living the privileged life of a princess in Dorne, but in fact has had a rather terrible life.

Even in the Game of Thrones' dark and bloody world, I thought that children would be safe from the scheming.

Do we ever find out more details of Myrcella's fate ?

Comment: Game of throne is a running TV series on a running book series, we can't know the end till it ends.

Comment: This question is wrong on so many levels. Here is why: GRRM the one that wrote the original books, used to work in TV. And hated how there's a sense of fake fate in the TV, how people live happily ever after is one of the things he hated, he wanted it to be more real. Second, Oberyn would never plan on invading a country. I mean NEVER !

Comment: @yondaime008 where does it say anything about invading a country ?

Comment: @Skeith Wasn't said, but hinted "Later Oberyn Martell arrives planning revenge against the Lannisters." Arrives at king landing?

Comment: @yondaime008 yes he came to kings landing for the sole reason of getting revenge on the lanisters for his sisters murder, its the only reason he was there. How do you get invade from that ?

Comment: *"This scene implies that Myrcella is not living the privileged life of a princess in Dorne, but in fact has had a rather terrible life"* - I'm not sure that's implied at all. At the most what it implies is that Cersei at least *thinks/fears* this.

Comment: @Skeith For some reason I mistook Oberyn Martell with Prince Doran Martell. I apologize :)

Comment: *SPOILER* May I however ensure you that through the books, Myrcella IS living the quite the princess life.

Comment: Though, I think the question might be salvagable and not necessarily closable. But I would have to take a further look to actually improve it.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I could answer, as the fate of Myrcella has been depicted pretty well in the 5th book of A Song Of Ice And Fire, but I believe this is a question for the series.

Comment: As for "I thought that children would be safe from the scheming": you do remember what Theon Greyjoy did to [two children](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/A_Man_Without_Honor)?

Comment: @BCdotWEB: or, indeed, what happens to Bran in the very first episode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This scene implies that Myrcella is not living the privileged life of a princess in Dorne, but in fact has had a rather terrible life

No not really. She is being treated as befits her rank as princess of the realm. Remember that she was sent with one of the Kingsguard to keep her safe. However, she *is* a hostage. That was the whole point of the plot to marry her off to a Martell prince. The Lannisters needed the loyalty of the Martells so that they could have a peaceful South, which leaves them free to fight the North. To do this they strengthen the bonds between the royal Baratheons and the Martells through marriage, and allow Princess Myrcella to become a hostage in Martell lands to ensure good conduct from the Lannisters. The Martells (despite Oberyn's wishes) do not desire war with the Lannisters, so Myrcella is kept safe.

The death of Joffrey Baratheon however has elevated the status of Myrcella Baratheon to a potential heir to the throne. In common Westerosi law, she is second in line after her younger brother Tommen (since males always have the stronger claim, despite their seniority). So when Tommen ascends the throne, she becomes the heir to the Iron Throne for the foreseeable future since Tommen is far too young to be producing heirs of his own. This is *further* complicated by a very important quirk in Dornish law. In Dorne, the senior heir has the strongest claims regardless of gender. So in Dornish eyes, Myrcella should be the Queen of Westeros, not Tommen. Oberyn even goes as far as hinting at this to Tyrion.

The upcoming season of the show will see us visiting Dorne, so Myrcella and her status in the succession will become a major plot point.

Answer (score 3):

> This scene implies that Myrcella is not living the privileged life of
>   a princess in Dorn, but in fact has had a rather terrible life.

Except that you misremember the scene instead of [looking it up](http://hollywoodlife.com/2014/05/05/game-of-thrones-cersei-lannister-more-sympathetic-first-of-his-name/):

> During their stroll, she could not have been kinder to Oberyn. Cersei
>   asked him if he could give a gift to Myrcella for her, since she
>   missed her birthday, and she asked him if her daughter is happy where
>   she is in Dorne. Oberyn, kind of taken aback, assured her that
>   Myrcella is happy — that “We don’t hurt little girls in Dorne,”
>   alluding, as ever, to Elia’s death. Cersei replied that “Everywhere in
>   the world, they hurt little girls.”

Myrcella is important for Dorne, because she's their hostage. And those get treated very well.

Moreover, she is an heir to the throne (though not directly -- except in Dorne) and if she were to birth a son with her Martell husband(-to-be) that child would be an actual heir, especially if the other Lannister children come to pass before producing any heirs themselves.